# Generate unique row combinations where all values in a row are treated as a single element

Tags: r

Attempting to generate each unique combination of rows where all values in a row are treated as a single element. For example:

```
  Var1  Var2  Var3 
1  a     b     a
2  b     a     c
3  c     c     b
4  d     d     d
```

Where it creates the combinations:

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6  
1  a    b    a    b    a    c
2  a    b    a    c    c    b
3  a    b    a    d    d    d
4  b    a    c    c    c    b
5  b    a    c    d    d    d
6  c    c    b    d    d    d
```

I'm playing around with Map using do.call(rbind, Map(expand.grid, l1, l2) but each variable is treated as a separate value whereas I need the entire row combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combs <- combn(1:nrow(df1), 2)
do.call(rbind, Map(function(i,j) cbind(df1[i,],df1[j,]), combs[1,], combs[2,]))
# Var1 Var2 Var3 Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1     a    b    a    b    a    c
# 11    a    b    a    c    c    b
# 12    a    b    a    d    d    d
# 2     b    a    c    c    c    b
# 21    b    a    c    d    d    d
# 3     c    c    b    d    d    d
```

This approach first creates combinations of the possible items. Each row represents one item in your case. Therefore it is possible to subset the data.frame based on the combination index. `Map` and `do.call(rbind, ..)` help to shorten the syntax but the important bit is `cbind(df1[i,], df1[j,])`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is it possible to extend this to create each unique row combinations using two dataframes compared to each other? For example my data can be split by 'left' and 'right' and I want to generate unique row combinations between left and right only, not within.

Comment: Hard to tell from your description. Try to create a working example with desired output to create a new question.

Comment: The comments section is not the best place to pose the question. Please create a new question with description and example data.

Comment: kk just put in a new question with the  example